# Why the many Python third-party library documentations are txt format,How to use them?

Tags: python, django

Like the django doc and docutils doc.

I am a Java programmer, jar doc all is html.
So i dont know how to use python txt doc

Comment: What?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ is full of HTML Django docs.

Comment: I think he meant how to convert rst format into html like django and docutils online docs, please go to sphinx: http://sphinx-doc.org its a tool that let you do that.

Comment: I wonder how many people have bookmarked this page to prove that Java programmers don't know how to read text files…

Comment: Java programmers don't read documentation at all...

Comment: @CRUSADER: Sure they do. But first they have to build a DocReaderAdapterFactoryFactory to build the DocReaderAdapterFactory to build the IDocReaderAdapter to adapter the IDocReader interface to read the IDocumentation for them. Which puts it in an Eclipse window—even if you're using emacs or NetBeans.

Comment: No, they don't. Experience tells us that Python programmers have to look up the API documentation for Java developers...this happens at least three times per day :-P

Comment: @CRUSADER: `public class PythonProgrammer implements IDocReader`?

Comment: If you can't open a txt file I don't know what's going on. If you want to run s txt as py, just change the file extension.

Answer (score 7):

Most documentation is nowadays authored using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).
The [Sphinx Python documentation generator](http://sphinx-doc.org/) can be used to convert those
documentation to PDF, HTML, LaTeX, EPUB and other formats.

Most Python documentation on packages.python.org or readthedocs.org
is actually generated from reStructuredText and Sphinx.

So your overall impression is just wrong.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It explains how to convert the text (rst) docs to HTML. What else do you need?

Comment: @abarnert It gets my upvote (if it was bad - I probably wouldn't have bothered (like yourself) doing a quick edit) - I can't see a reason for a downvote either...

Comment: @CRUSADER thanks , my impression is wrong, I mistakenly thought it was normal text

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is partly a tactic to encourage users to refer to the online documentation - in Django's case this is explicitly recommended.

However it is possible to generate a local HTML copy of the Django documentation as per the following link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/whatsnext/?from=olddocs#as-html-locally

Since the Python Standard Library documentation is also generated using Sphinx, it should also be possible to generate a local HTML version.